# error NU1002: The dependency Npgsql 3.1.0-alpha5 in project XXX does not support framework .NETPlatform,Version=v5.4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, npgsql

I have a project.json like this `

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "XXX Class Library",
  "authors": [ "Class Library template" ],
  "tooling": {
    "defaultNamespace": "XXX"
  },   
  "dependencies": {
    "Npgsql": "3.1.0-*"
  }, 
  "frameworks": {
    "dotnet5.4": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
        "System.Data.Common": "4.0.1-*"         
      }
    },
    "dnxcore50": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-*",
        "System.Collections": "4.0.11-*",
        "System.Console": "4.0.0-*",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.1-*",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.11-*",
        "System.Data.Common": "4.0.1-*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I run dnu restore I get no errors, but when I run dnu build I get this error:

> error NU1002: The dependency Npgsql 3.1.0-alpha5 in project XXX does
>   not support framework .NETPlatform,Version=v5.4.

How can I troubleshoot this?

Many Thanks

Comment: Does your project mix csproj and xproj project types (ie previous project type and new dotnet core type)?